# how to add expand all button with contextmenu to d3.js tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tree, contextmenu

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
 })
.on("click", click).on("contextmenu", function (data, index) {          
      d3.event.preventDefault();
       // add context menu...
     });;
```

You can see my code above. I am new on d3.js and I couldn't find how to add an Expand All button on a context menu. Thanks for your helps..
P.S: I mustn't use Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to implement a context menu using D3. First create a global variable for displaying the custom menu `var contextDiv;`. Then bind a click event to your svg element:

```
d3.select("svg").on("contextmenu", clickFunction);
```

And implement the function.

```
function clickFunction() {
    event.preventDefault();

    contextDiv = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("top", event.pageY + 1 + "px")
        .style("left", event.pageX + 1 + "px");
    var contextTable = contextDiv.append("table")
        .style("border", "solid 1px");

    contextTable.append("tr")
        .append("td").text("Expand All").attr("id", "citem1");
    contextTable.append("tr")
        .append("td").text("Item2").attr("id", "citem2");
    contextTable.append("tr")
        .append("td").text("Item3").attr("id", "citem3");
    contextTable.on("click", tableClick);
}
```

Now implement the `tableClick` function.

```
function tableClick(){
    var target = d3.event.target.id;
    contextDiv.remove();

    if (target == "citem1")
        expand(root);
}
```

And finally the `expandAll` function. Note that `root` variable must be defined as the root of the tree. This is assuming you're basing your tree off [This](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example.

```
function expand(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d.children.forEach(expand);
        d._children = null;
    } else if (d.children) {
        d.children.forEach(expand);
    }
}
```

There is a lot more you'll have to do if you want your context menu to behave exactly like the inbuilt one, but this should be enough to get you started. Also, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bgnaou7/) is a Fiddle with this behavior built in.